# Should I clear unused javascript arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory-management

I'm working on a page that, eventually, could have more than 100 arrays, only a few of which would be used at any given time.

At the moment, I'm populating all arrays as global variables, but I suspect this is inefficient in terms of memory use.

Should I change my code to clear the arrays when they are not being used? If so, what is the best way to do this? I'd guess `var myArray = new array()` but perhaps there's a better option.

Comment: If you want to "free" a value for garbage collection, make sure no variables or property refers to it. You can achieve this by assigning any other value to the variable, e.g. `null`.

Comment: It sure sounds like you should NOT have 100 global arrays if you are only using a few of them at any given time.  A proper design would not have lots of usused global data sitting around.  More likely this data should either be local in scope and only used by a certain function or should be attached to an object that is kept around only while being used.  The real answer here is that you need to fix your design so that state is kept in objects who only exist when they are being used.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for that. I came to the same conclusion overnight, and changed my structure so that just a few arrays are repopulated with new data as required.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have many thousands of objects in your arrays, you don't need to worry. Don't prematurely optimize your code; the browser is quite good at handling lots of small objects.

If memory does become an issue or you notice performance issues, you can simply reassign a new array to those variables:

```
myArray = [];
```

The garbage collector will clean up the objects that you dereferenced.

In a broader case, if there's no need to keep references to those objects, you don't even need the arrays to begin with. I.e., if you never access the elements that you put in the arrays a second time, just remove the arrays and don't bother assigning the data.